# OVerride a url mapping defined in a controller present in a jar

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring-security-oauth2 jar file. During the oauth verification process it makes a call to **"/oauth/token"** and hence the method. I want to modify the method..

Is it possible if i can override the url mapping already present? or exlcude the class from jar..

Thanks
Harshit